# LWC : Issue on invalid input or characters onKeyDown

Tags: lightning-web-components, validation, lightninginput, invalid

On console logs when toggle switch this.isToggled is false, onKeyDown this.inputPattern became [a-zA-Z]* which is correct. I shouldn't be able to type any number when this.isToggled = false. But I can still type invalid input. What could be the problem in this case.

HTML

```
<lightning-input type="text" value={value} onchange={handleChange} onkeydown={handleKeyDown}   pattern={inputPattern} message-when-pattern-mismatch={inputErrorMessage}></lightning-input>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
get inputPattern() {
    return this.isLettersOnly ? '[a-zA-Z]*' : '/[0-9\.]/';
}

get inputErrorMessage() {
    return this.isLettersOnly ? 'Please enter a valid text' : 'Please enter a valid number';
}

handleKeyDown(event) {
    console.log('handleKeyDown');
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    const keyPressed = event.key;

    if(event.key.length === 1 && !event.key.match(this.inputPattern)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

changeToggle(event){
    this.isLettersOnly = !this.isLettersOnly;
    this.isToggled = !this.isToggled;
    if(this.isToggled){
        this.isLettersOnly = false;
    }else{
        this.isLettersOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't put regular expressions in a string, as they will be interpreted differently. They should be normal regular expressions.

```
return this.isLettersOnly ? /[a-zA-Z]/ : /[0-9\.]/;
```

Comment: Great Thank you. I overlooked that part. It's working now :)